# WXPython: getting the initial value of a combo box

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

In  a  dialog box I have a combo box and a text field. I would like to make so that if one particular value in the combo box is selected, the text  field  would  be  disabled  (or hidden), and if another value is selected, the text field would be enabled.
I have:

```
self.myCombo = wx.ComboBox(parent=self, choices=['value1', 'value2'], style = wx.CB_READONLY)
self.myCombo.Bind(wx.EVT_COMBOBOX, self.onChange)
# ...

def onChange(self, ev):
    self.myTextField.Enable(False)      if     self.myCombo.GetValue() != "value1" else self.myTextField.Enable(True)
```

And  this  does  work  like  a  charm, the text field gets enabled and disabled.
However,  I  would  like  to  have  the text field enabled or disabled depending  on  the  initial  value of the combo box, meaning the value gotten from a config file and selected when the dialog box is open.
I've tried the same:

```
self.myTextField = wx.TextCtrl(parent=self)
self.myTextField.Enable(False)  if self.myCombo.GetValue() != "value1" else self.myTextField.Enable(True)
```

but  this doesn't work. I've tried `GetSelection` also, but when logging this, both `GetValue` and `GetSelection` return -1.

Comment: GetSelection and GetValue should work.  Could you please give a full but minimal working example where they don't.  That is, your problem probably has something to do with the state of myCombo, but from your code, one really can't tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The combobox probably isn't fully initialized yet when you try to query it. If you want to disable it when it loads, you don't have to check its value. Just disable it. But for what you want to do, I would recommend using wxPython's [wx.CallAfter()](http://wiki.wxpython.org/CallAfter) method.

Something like the following should suffice:

```
def __init__(self):
    # initialize various variables

    wx.CallAfter(self.check_combobox, args)

def check_combobox(self, args):
    self.myTextField.Enable(False) if self.myCombo.GetValue() != "value1" else self.myTextField.Enable(True)
```